# How can we extract size_is relationship from PS(Proxy/Stub) files in COM?

Tags: c#, com, pia, typelib

I need to extract size_is and all other attributes such as "length_is","max_is" etc attributes information from proxy/stub in C# , as these information skipped out while making Type Library, so i cannot use ITypeInfo, or ITypeLib interfaces for this task.

Is there any other way to extract these attributes,I need to extract this in C#.

Regards
Usman